# How to simplify $\sin^4 (x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Folks, how can $\sin^4(x)$ be simplified to a trig function with power of 1? I tried:
$(\sin^2(x))^2 = ((1-\cos2x)/2)^2$ but still getting $\cos x$ to the power of $2$. Wolframalpha only shows the answer which i have no idea how they got it. 
Could somebody help ?

Comment: This is the correct first step.  Now you have to do the same for $\cos^2(2x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y,$

$$(2\sin^2x)^2=(1-\cos2x)^2=1-2\cos2x+\cos^22x$$

Use $\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$ for $\cos^22x$

---

Alternatively using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $2i\sin y=e^{iy}-e^{-iy};2\cos y=e^{iy}+e^{-iy}$

$$\sin^4x=\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^4$$

$$\displaystyle=\dfrac{e^{i4x}+e^{-i4x}-\binom41(e^{i2x}+e^{-i2x})+\binom42}{16}=?$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem has be simplified so that any trig function would have only a power of 1 while we're getting cos^2 (2x)

Comment: @Meaghan,  Don't you notice : Use $\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$ for $\cos^22x$

Comment: But how can i use what you have mentioned ?

Comment: @Meaghan, If  $\cos^2y=\dfrac{1+\cos2y}2,\cos^22x=?$

Answer (score 5):

$\sin^4(x) = \left(\sin^4 x\right)^\color{red}{1}$. Jokes apart,
$$\sin^4(x) = \left(1-\cos^2(x)\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{4} $$
hence:
$$\sin^4(x) = \frac{3}{8}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{\cos(4x)}{8}=\frac{3-4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)}{8}.$$

I have just applied the Pythagorean theorem ($\sin^2 z+\cos^2 z=1$) and twice the cosine duplication formula ($\cos(2z)=2\cos^2 z-1$, giving $\cos^2(z)=\frac{1+\cos(2z)}{2}$).

Comment: Can you explain how you got the answer?

Comment: @Meaghan: done.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have used a trigonometrical/algebraic approach to the problem, this answer showcases a different method that exploits the relationship between $z^n \pm z^{-n}$ for complex numbers $z$.

We know that $$z^n - z^{-n} = 2i\sin n\theta \implies z - z^{-1} = 2i\sin \theta \\ z^n +z^{-n} = 2\cos n\theta \implies z + z^{-1} = 2\cos \theta$$ from a basic application of De Moivre's theorem.

So, it follows immediately that $$\begin{align}(2i \sin \theta)^4 &= (z-z^{-1})^4 \\ 
&=z^4 + \frac{1}{z^4} - 4\left(z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}\right) + 6 \\ 
&= 2\cos 4\theta - 8\cos 2\theta + 6\end{align}$$

So we have, finally $$16 \sin^4 \theta = 2\cos 4\theta - 8\cos 2\theta + 6$$

So dividing through by $16$ yields $$\bbox[border: solid 1px blue, 10px]{\sin^4 \theta = \frac{1}{8} \cos 4\theta - \frac{1}{2}\cos 2\theta + \frac{3}{8}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^4 x = (\sin^2x)^2$$

By using identity $\sin^2 x = 1- \cos^2 x$, we can change $\sin^4 x$ to:

$$\sin^4 x = (1-\cos^2 x)^2$$

$\cos^2 x$ can be changed by using identity $\cos 2x= 2\cos^2 x-1$, then $\cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$

So, $\sin^4 x = (1-\frac12-\frac12\cos 2x)^2$

$$=(\frac12-\frac12\cos 2x)^2$$
$$= \frac14(1-\cos 2x)^2$$
$$= \frac14(1-2\cos2x+\cos^2 2x)$$

Also change $\cos^2 2x$ by using identity $\cos 4x= \cos 2(2x)= 2\cos^2 2x-1$.

So $\cos^2 2x= \frac12(\cos 4x+1)$

$$= \frac14(1-2\cos2x +(\cos 4x+1)/2)$$
$$= \frac14(1-2\cos2x +\frac12\cos4x +\frac12)$$
$$= \frac14(3/2 -2\cos2x +\frac12\cos 4x)$$

Finally the answer should be:

$$\sin^4x= \frac38 - \frac12\cos(2x) + \frac18\cos(4x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using de Moivre's theorem

Let z be a complex number such that |z| = 1

Hence z + 1/z = 2isin(x)

(2isin(x))^4 = (z- 1/z)^4

Therefore:

Villager 1: Think it's in there?

Villager 2: All right. Let's get it!

Villager 1: Whoa. Hold on. Do you know what that thing can do to you?

Villager 3: Yeah, it'll grind your bones for it's bread.

Shrek chuckles, revealing himself to be standing behind the mob.

SHREK: Yes, well, actually, that would be a giant.

The mob gasp.

SHREK: Now, ogres, oh they're much worse. They'll make a suit from your freshly peeled skin...

Shrek slowly approaches as the villagers back away in fear.

Villagers: No!

SHREK: They'll shave your liver. Squeeze the jelly from your eyes! Actually, it's quite good on toast.

Villager 1: Back! Back, beast! Back! I warn ya! (Waves the torch at Shrek.)

Shrek licks his fingers and extinguishes the torch. The men shrink back away from him. Shrek terrifies the mob with a great frightening roar, his spit extinguishing all the remaining torches.

SHREK: (Whispering) This is the part where you run away.

The men drop their torches and pitchforks and flee as fast they can.

SHREK: And stay out! (looks down and picks up a wanted poster. Reads.) "Wanted. Fairytale creatures." (He sighs and drops the paper on the ground.)

Hence

sin^4(x) = (i/8)(sin4x) + (i/2)sin2x + 3/8

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please consider: (1) using mathjax, (2) removing the conversation your wrote.