# Calculus 2 Trig Integrals: $\sin^4(x)$ included in integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> $$\int_0^{1/4} 3\sin^42\pi x\,\mathrm dx$$

Below is my work:  As you can see, I think my final line equals zero which I don't think is the right answer.

1) please let me know where I went wrong
2) a step through of problem would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: It certainly can be right, for $\sin^4$ is positive almost everywhere, hence the integral must be positive.

Comment: $ 3 \sin^4 2 \pi x = \frac{3 \cos 8 \pi x - 12 \cos 4 \pi x + 9}{8} $

Comment: see answer by Jack : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370226/how-to-simplify-sin4-x

Comment: I think your work is fine.  It doesn't give zero at the end because of the $3x/2$ term at the end.  All the trig bits make zero, but the last bit gives $9/32$, the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\text{Let } I = \int_0^{1/4} 3\sin^4(2\pi x) \, dx$$

Let $u = 2 \pi x \implies \frac{du}{dx} = 2 \pi$. Then we get:

$$I = \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \sin^4(u) \,du$$

Apply product-to-sum formulas

> $$\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \cos(2x) \right)$$
>   $$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \cos(2x) \right)$$

and we will get:

$$\frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \sin^4(u) \,du$$
$$= \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \left(\frac{1 - \cos(2u)}{2} \right)^2 \,du$$
$$= \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \frac{\cos^2(2u) - 2\cos(2u) + 1}{4} \,du$$
$$= \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \frac{\frac{1 + \cos(4u)}{2} - 2\cos(2u) + 1}{4} \,du$$
$$= \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int \frac{1 + \cos(4u) - 4\cos(2u) + 2}{8} \,du$$
$$= \frac{3}{2 \pi} \left( \int \frac{\cos(4u)}{8}\,du - \int \frac{\cos(2u)}{2}\,du + \int \frac{3}{8}\,du \right)$$

Solving each indefinite integral and we get:

$$I = \frac{3}{2 \pi} \left( \frac{\sin(4u)}{32} - \frac{\sin(2u)}{4} + \frac{3}{8}u  + C\right)$$
$$= \frac{3\sin(4u)}{64 \pi} - \frac{3\sin(2u)}{8 \pi} + \frac{9}{16 \pi}u  + C$$

Undo substitution to get:

> $$I = \frac{3\sin(8 \pi x)}{64 \pi} - \frac{3\sin(4 \pi x)}{8 \pi} + \frac{9}{8}x  + C$$

Therefore:

> $$\int_0^{1/4} 3\sin^4(2\pi x) \, dx = \left.\left(\frac{3\sin(8 \pi x)}{64 \pi} - \frac{3\sin(4 \pi x)}{8 \pi} + \frac{9}{8}x  + C \right)\right\rvert_0^{1/4} = \frac{9}{32}$$

Answer (score 0):

I really would separate the integral and the identity. My first try gave
$$ 8 \sin^4 t = \cos 4t - 4 \cos 2t + 3 $$
$$  \sin^4 t = \frac{ \cos 4t - 4 \cos 2t + 3}{8} $$
$$  \sin^4 2 \pi x = \frac{ \cos 8 \pi x - 4 \cos 4 \pi x + 3}{8} $$
$$ 3 \sin^4 2 \pi x = \frac{3 \cos 8 \pi x - 12 \cos 4 \pi x + 9}{8} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Do you know the following reduction formula?

$$\int\sin^nt\,\mathrm dt = \dfrac{n - 1}n\int\sin^{n - 2}t\,\mathrm dt - \dfrac{\cos t\sin^{n - 1}t}{n}$$

---

Let $t = 2\pi x\implies \mathrm dx = \dfrac1{2\pi}\mathrm dt$. Then,

$$\int 3\sin^42\pi x\,\mathrm dx\equiv \dfrac3{2\pi}\int\sin^4t\,\mathrm dt$$

Use the reduction formula with $n = 4$.

$$\begin{align}\int\sin^4t\,\mathrm dt &= \dfrac34\int\sin^2\,\mathrm dt - \dfrac{\cos t\sin^3t}4 \\
&=\dfrac34\left(\dfrac12t - \dfrac{\cos t\sin t}2\right) - \dfrac{\cos t \sin^3t}4 \\ &=\dfrac38t - \dfrac{\cos t\sin t}8 - \dfrac{\cos t\sin^3t}4\end{align}$$

Reverse substitution and plug limits

$$\int_0^{1/4}3\sin^42\pi x\,\mathrm dx = \left.\dfrac3{2\pi}\left(\dfrac68\pi x - \dfrac{\cos 2\pi x\sin 2\pi x}8 - \dfrac{\cos 2\pi x\sin^32\pi x}4\right)\right\rvert_0^{1/4} = \dfrac9{32}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=2\pi x$. Then,

$$\int_0^{1/4} 3\sin^4(2\pi x)dx =\frac3{2\pi}I$$

Integrate by parts,

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^4 t dt =-\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3 t\> d(\cos t) 
= 3 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 t \cos^2 t dt $$
$$= 3 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 t (1-\sin^2 t) dt 
= 3 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 tdt - 3I $$

Then,

$$I = \frac34\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 tdt = \frac{3\pi}{16}$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^{1/4} 3\sin^4(2\pi x)dx = \frac3{2\pi}I =\frac9{32}$$

Comment: Don't you mean $\dfrac9{32}$?